# ¿Por qué no puedo llegar al final de un span con CTRL + Flecha?

Tags: html

¿Por qué no puedo llegar al final de un span con editableContent con CTRL + Flecha derecha si hay otro span al lado?

```html
<span contenteditable="true">No puedo seleccionar la última palabra con CTRL + Flecha Derecha => ultimaPalabra</span>

<span contenteditable="true">¿Viste? No estás siendo capaz de llegar al final del previo span con CTRL + Flecha derecha<span>
```

Comment: Se ve que es un "bug" de elementos con `display: inline` (_y sus combinaciones_), si lo cambias a `block` se "arrelga"

Answer (score 1):

tal como te han indicado anteriormente, parece un bug.
Recree el mismo escenario en diferentes navegadores pero el comportamiento es el esperado.
Te dejo el siguiente código para que puedas ver los cambios.
De igual forma en el siguiente [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display) puedes ver todos los atributos que tiene esta propiedad, para futuros desarrollos. Saludos

```css
#cont1{
   display:inline;
   padding:2vh;
 }
 
#cont2{
   display:block;
   padding:2vh;
 }
```

```html
<span id=cont1 contenteditable="true">No puedo seleccionar la última palabra con CTRL + Flecha Derecha => ultimaPalabra</span>
<hr>
<span id=cont2 contenteditable="true">No puedo seleccionar la última palabra con CTRL + Flecha Derecha => ultimaPalabra</span>
```

Comment: ¿Entonces no hay forma de usar varios spans en los que estén juntos (aparentando ser un solo texto continuo) sin que ocurra el bug, cierto? Igualmente, ya reporté el bug en: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1296388